# Problems with current web AI systems

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm going into my third year of studies as an AI student and am planning my third year project. I have been considering a recommendation system of some sort. The motivation for this is to gain an understanding of how people evaluate products (what makes the products desirable) and consequently attempt to build a system that would understand this. Currently my thinking is along the lines of a system that would be able to differentiate between different priorities in peoples' likes and dislikes. For instance a person who is environmentally very aware probably wouldn't want to buy products that are not.

So the question is
- What things are most in need of repair/development in the modern web AI systems (Google, Amazon, Last.fm and so on).

My project is limited to about 6 months but I would be interested to hear any thought on the subject.

Comment: How the hell did the [subjective] tag just [rise from the dead](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Comment: @BoltClock Apparently they have been removed from search listings, but you can still tag questions as [subjective]

Comment: Oh crap - the rules changed yesterday. I stand forever corrected. Oh and yes, the tag thingy indeed even suggests it after typing [subj] although I did wonder how come there were 0 of them when in the past there has been so many.

Comment: @maffel: my previous comment contains a link to the respective blog post detailing the recent meta-tag purge.

Comment: Isn't calling Google/Amazon/Last.fm "AI systems" using the term a bit loosely? "AI" barely means anything at all anymore. If we start calling arbitrary websites "AI", it will have officially lost all meaning.

Comment: @Chris S: I didn't call arbitrary websites AI but specifically chose Google, Amazon and Last.fm because they all use AI methods. Natural language processing and machine learning, probably symbolic and non symbolic. I agree that AI is a broad term, that's exactly why I mentioned specific websites to give some idea on what I'm talking about. You may notice the lack of speech recognition and autonomous embodied agents.

Comment: @maffel, I would not consider those websites to be using "AI methods".

Comment: @Chris S: So what you're saying is NLP and Machine Learning are not AI methods. You seem to have been using the AI tag yourself so I am now interested on what you think is AI?

Comment: @maffel, NLP and machine learning are AI. Google and Amazon are companies, not AI. Google and Amazon employ very narrow implementations of AI technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things that you might want to look at are Facebook OpenSocial Graph and Google Prediction API.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll look into the prediction API.